# Shortcut for adding <li> around already written <a>

Tags: html

Please excuse my poor vocabulary when it comes to programming and coding, I am just getting started.

I want a shortcut to add li /li or something similar around text that is already written instead of going through the start and end of each one and write it on each individual line.
I also want to do this to multiple lines at the time, if possible.

[I want a shortcut for changing the first line to the second one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGjZ6.png)

Comment: It's totally depends on the editor which you are using. From the image I guess that you are using VSCode, so select your inner html then ctrl + shift+ p, type: abbrev (will be the first item next time you ctrl + shift+ p) and enter, type: li and Enter.

You can also install one of htmltagwrappers plugins or key bind the first approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "find and replace all" With whatever editor you are using

Search for `<a href=` and replace with `<li><a href=`

Similarly search for `</a>` and replace with `</a></li>`